# Neural network back propagation writing in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to illustrate back-propagation algorithm. I follow the online course "Machine Learning" teach by Prof Andrew Ng and I completed code in Octave. With Octave program, it uses optimized function "fmincg". Now I don't want to use that function. Instead, I use traditional updating way:

```
theta = theta - alpha*dJ/dthea
```

I use dataset "iris.arff" for testing. The network has 3 layers, 4 units for input, 3 units for hidden layers and 3 units for output layer. I use java lib "ejml" for matrix computation.

My code runs 10000 epochs, the cost function J(theta) decreases after each epoch and the final value is approximately 0.7.
However, when I use my trained parameters to test again the dataset, the successful percentage is very low. It always outputs mostly only class 1, 2 or 3.
Can you show me where I'm wrong?
Here is my source code on [github](https://github.com/lenhhoxung86/NeutralNetwork).

To use, firstly run class "NeutralNetwork.java". The trained params are saved in file "netparams.txt". To test again, run class "PerformanceChecker.java".

Here are some relevant functions:

Cost Function:

```
public static ImmutableTriple<Double, DenseMatrix64F, DenseMatrix64F> calculateCostAndDerivatives(
        DenseMatrix64F theta1,
        DenseMatrix64F theta2,
        int inputNum,
        int hiddenNum,
        int classNum,
        DenseMatrix64F X,
        DenseMatrix64F y,
        double lambda) {

    ImmutableTriple<Double, DenseMatrix64F, DenseMatrix64F> retVal=null;
    Equation eq = new Equation();
    //-number of examples
    int m=X.getNumRows();
    double J=0;
    //-make aliases 
    eq.alias(m, "m");
    eq.alias(theta1, "Theta1");
    eq.alias(theta2, "Theta2");
    eq.alias(inputNum, "inputNum");
    eq.alias(hiddenNum, "hiddenNum");
    eq.alias(classNum, "classNum");
    eq.alias(X, "X");
    eq.alias(y, "y");
    eq.alias(lambda, "lambda");

    //-init Theta1_grad
    eq.process("Theta1_grad=zeros("+theta1.getNumRows()+","+theta1.getNumCols()+")");
    //-init Theta2_grad
    eq.process("Theta2_grad=zeros("+theta2.getNumRows()+","+theta2.getNumCols()+")");

    //-common operator to handle basic matrix operations
    CommonOps op=new CommonOps();

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        /***************** Forward propagation *********************/
        //-extract example at line row i
        DenseMatrix64F X1=op.extractRow(X, i, null);
        eq.alias(X1, "X1");

        //-activation at the input layer
        eq.process("A1=[1 X1]'");

        //-calculate activation vector for the hidden layer
        eq.process("z2=Theta1*A1");
        DenseMatrix64F a2=sigmoid(eq.lookupMatrix("z2"));
        eq.alias(a2, "a2");
        eq.process("A2=[1;a2]");

        //-calculate activation vector for the output layer
        eq.process("z3=Theta2*A2");
        DenseMatrix64F a3=sigmoid(eq.lookupMatrix("z3"));
        eq.alias(a3, "a3");

        //-build output vector
        eq.process("yvec=zeros(classNum,1)");
        DenseMatrix64F yvec=eq.lookupMatrix("yvec");
        yvec.set((int)Math.round(y.get(i)-1), 0, 1);

        //-calculate cost J
        eq.process("h=-yvec .* log(a3) - (1 - yvec) .* log(1-a3)");
        DenseMatrix64F h=eq.lookupMatrix("h");
        J+=op.elementSum(h);

        /********************* Start back propagation here ********************/
        eq.process("delta3=a3-yvec");
        DenseMatrix64F sgZ2=sigmoidGradient(eq.lookupMatrix("z2"));
        eq.alias(sgZ2, "sgZ2");
        eq.process("delta2=((Theta2')*delta3) .* [1;sgZ2]");
        eq.process("delta2=delta2(1:,0:)");

        //-calculate theta gradient
        eq.process("Theta2_grad=Theta2_grad + (delta3 * (A2'))");
        eq.process("Theta1_grad=Theta1_grad + (delta2 * (A1'))");
    }

    //-update cost function again
    J = J/m;

    //-update theta gradient
    eq.process("Theta1_grad=Theta1_grad / m");
    eq.process("Theta2_grad=Theta2_grad / m");

    //-regularize cost value
    DenseMatrix64F mainTheta1=op.extract(theta1, 0, theta1.getNumRows(), 1, theta1.getNumCols());
    DenseMatrix64F mainTheta2=op.extract(theta2, 0, theta2.getNumRows(), 1, theta2.getNumCols());
    op.elementPower(mainTheta1, 2, mainTheta1);
    double term1=op.elementSum(mainTheta1);

    op.elementPower(mainTheta2, 2, mainTheta2);
    double term2=op.elementSum(mainTheta2);

    double regTerm=(lambda*(term1+term2))/(2*m);
    J+=regTerm;

    //-regularize theta gradient
    eq.process("regTerm1=(Theta1 * lambda) / m");
    eq.process("regTerm1(0:,0)=zeros(hiddenNum,1)");
    eq.process("Theta1_grad=Theta1_grad+regTerm1");

    eq.process("regTerm2=(Theta2 * lambda) / m");
    eq.process("regTerm2(0:,0)=zeros(classNum,1)");
    eq.process("Theta2_grad=Theta2_grad+regTerm2");

    //-build return value here
    Double costJ=new Double(J);
    retVal=ImmutableTriple.of(costJ, eq.lookupMatrix("Theta1_grad"), eq.lookupMatrix("Theta2_grad"));

    return retVal;
}
```

Here is the sigmoid:

```
/**
 * Sigmoid function - logistics function
 * @param inputMatrix
 * @return
 */
public static DenseMatrix64F sigmoid(DenseMatrix64F inputMatrix) {
    Equation eq=new Equation();
    eq.alias(inputMatrix, "inM");
    eq.process("outM=(1 / (1 + exp(-inM)))");

    return eq.lookupMatrix("outM");
}

/**
 * Sigmoid gradient function
 * @param inputMatrix
 * @return
 */
public static DenseMatrix64F sigmoidGradient(DenseMatrix64F inputMatrix) {
    Equation eq=new Equation();
    DenseMatrix64F s1=sigmoid(inputMatrix);
    eq.alias(s1, "s1");
    eq.process("s2=1-s1");
    eq.process("g=s1 .* s2");

    return eq.lookupMatrix("g");
}
```

And here is the main loop:

```
public static void runGradientDescent(int epochNum, ImmutablePair<DenseMatrix64F, DenseMatrix64F> trainingSet) {
    DenseMatrix64F theta1=ParamOptimizer.randInitializeWeights(4, 3);
    DenseMatrix64F theta2=ParamOptimizer.randInitializeWeights(3, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < epochNum; i++) {
        System.out.println("***** epoch "+(i+1)+"*****");
        ImmutableTriple<Double, DenseMatrix64F, DenseMatrix64F> result=CostCalculator.calculateCostAndDerivatives(
                theta1, 
                theta2, 
                Constants.numberOfInputUnits, 
                Constants.numberOfHiddedUnits, 
                Constants.numberOfOutputUnits, 
                trainingSet.getLeft(), 
                trainingSet.getRight(), 
                Constants.lambda);
        System.out.println("epoch "+(i+1)+" - J="+result.getLeft());

        //-update theta values
        CommonOps op=new CommonOps();

        DenseMatrix64F theta1_grad=result.getMiddle();
        op.scale(Constants.alpha, theta1_grad);
        op.subtract(theta1, theta1_grad, theta1);

        DenseMatrix64F theta2_grad=result.getRight();
        op.scale(Constants.alpha, theta2_grad);
        op.subtract(theta2, theta2_grad, theta2);
    }
    saveWeightsToFile("netparams.txt",theta1,theta2);
    System.out.println("Network parameters saved!");
}
```

Comment: Please try to find the relevant part of the code, then post it here instead of linking to it on Github. Unfortunately, backpropagation can be a bitch to troubleshoot. You can try gradient checking as a sanity check if you haven't already, and try to work backwards to find out what's wrong.

Comment: I add relevant functions as you suggested, thanks.

Comment: I also generated random initial parameters for weights as u see above.

Comment: I don't see a learning rate anywhere, what do you set that to? Make sure you try with various number of epochs and learning rates so as not to overfit. There's a reason `fmincg` is used in the Coursera lectures: it's better because it doesn't need you to fiddle with learning rates and epochs, which can drastically affect the performance of your ANN.

Comment: I set learning rate in constant "Constants.alpha" with value of 0.1. Actually, I don't know how to set it. I see it's the default value for multi perceptron in Weka so I just simply copy and use it. Do we need different learning rates for different layers?

Comment: Anyway, I also implement "gradient checking" as in the course and the values are indeed approximate, so I'm sure that my calculation for partial derivatives is correct. Is there any optimization function that I can use for Java ?